# Simple While Loop stuck in Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Every time I run this block of code, Python IDLE starts spamming 1's and 2's on the screen. I'm using Python 3.3 so there may be something I'm missing here:

```
count=1
```

And then as a separate entry:

```
while count<=5:
print count
count+1
```

The book I'm reading from is slightly outdated so I realise that print is a function and the correct way to write it would be:

```
print(count)
```

But as aside from that, I'm stuck and it keeps spamming 1's and 2's. What it's meant to do is automatically count from 1 to 5. And while I'm here, how many other updates should I be aware of from 2.7 to 3.3?

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the value of `count`, to do this you should assign the result of `count + 1` to it:

```
count = count + 1
```

or even simpler:

```
count += 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, do you mean in replacement of "count+1"?

Comment: Yes. If you want to modify a variable, you have to assign a new value to it. `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: Right I get you, and that modification worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Christian says, just replace the `count=1` with `count= count+1` or `count+=1`. The while loop continues until it's condition is false. `count + 1` just calculates a new count; it doesn't actually store it. A working example:

```
count= 1
while count<=5:
    print(count)
    count= count+1 #calculates a new count AND stores it
```

This produces the expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

On a side note, you might want to be careful about starting your count at one, and using the `<=` operator to stop it. Python and most other languages tend to start the count at 0, and then end it right before the 'limit' with the `<` operator instead. A small string example illustrating the 'first' character referenced with a '0' instead of the more obvious '1':

```
word= 'spam'
print(word[0]) #the first character
print(word[3]) #the second character
print(word[4]) #not in the string. Produces error.
```

And the results are:

```
's'
'm'
IndexError:string index out of range
```

The following code does the same thing and is more consistent with other python syntax:

```
count= 0
while count < 5:
    count= count+1
    print(count)
```

Or if you like incrementing the count at the end:

```
count= 0
while count < 5:
    print(count+1)
    count= count+1
```

Either of these ways use the more traditional route of starting a count to n at 0 and incrementing until n-1. It may seem more confusing at first, but it will pay off later. Good luck! I hope I didn't just delve into unnecessary detail when all you really needed was one line :)